# Play framework 2.3.8: Static assets not working in Production

Tags: playframework

Before a week i upgraded my play (2.2.3) project to 2.3.8. I started the app with

activator run

When tried to load image from public folder in Java Controller, it loaded and i did not have any issue. But when i try to start app using,

activator start

it did not loads. It seems there is no public folder within in universal folder. That caused the problem.

How to resolve it? Where to place our static assets in 2.3.8 project? How to package it to production?

Comment: Can you put the assets route in your routes file? And, have you tried to do "activator clean" ?